# Extend Container behind system bottom navigation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to extend an expanded scaffold with a child container behind the system bottom navigation bar to the very end of the screen. You can see it in the picture(black system bottom navigation bar of android phones). Not just to the limit of the system bottom navigation bar. I'm trying to make the system bottom navigation bar transparent and extend the scaffold with a child container underneath the navigation bar. Is it possible in flutter?

[image]

Comment: it would be great if you include some snippet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I've added an image and edited my questions to that you can understand.

Comment: Try below answer , that may solve your case,

Answer (score 1):

You can use extendBody

```dart
Scaffold(
 extendBody:true,
 ...
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html

> If true, and bottomNavigationBar or persistentFooterButtons is specified, then the body extends to the bottom of the Scaffold, instead of only extending to the top of the bottomNavigationBar or the persistentFooterButtons.

Answer (score -1):

You can use  `floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,` on Fab

```dart
 return Scaffold(
 
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
          child: Text(
            "Shop Now",
            maxLines: 1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Or use custom Fab position extending `FloatingActionButtonLocation`

```dart
class CustomFabPosition extends FloatingActionButtonLocation {
  @override
  Offset getOffset(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    return Offset(
        scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.width / 2 -
            scaffoldGeometry.floatingActionButtonSize.width / 2,
        scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.height * .85);
  }
}
```

And use on `floatingActionButtonLocation: CustomFabPosition(),`

If you need more customization over UI. use `Stack` widget.